# JMeter - Extract value from JSON response and update variable

Tags: java, jmeter, performance

My goal is to create a Google Drive CRUD with JMeter.
I was able to upload files with proper OAuth configuration.

However, I am struggling in extracting the response data to be used in further HTTP Requests.

The response of the upload is this simple JSON:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "blablabla",
 "name": "Untitled",
 "mimeType": "text/plain"
}
```

I would need to fetch this *id* in a PostProcessor component and update a JMeter variable with this value. This way I could reference to this value in the Read, Update and Delete requests.

I've tried to use the JSON Extractor and BeanShell, but I was unsucessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract this `id` value into a JMeter Variable the relevant [Json Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be as simple as:

```
$.id
```

You can verify this yourself using `JSON Path Tester` mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image]

So if you add a JSON Extractor as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and configure it like:

[image]

JMeter will store it into `id` variable as it evidenced by the [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler):

[image]

Going forward you should be able to access this value as `${id}` where required:

[image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)